# How to justify this asymptotic relation?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers

I am reading the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987005/number-of-integers-at-most-x-with-exactly-two-distinct-prime-factors/3987736#3987736) by Daniel Fischer. I understand most of the steps, except for his claim that
\begin{align*}
& \pi(\sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log \sqrt{x}} - \int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}} \pi(u) \frac{d}{du}\biggl(\frac{x}{u(\log x - \log u)}\biggr)\,du \\
&\sim -\int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}} \operatorname{Li}(u)\frac{d}{du}\biggl(\frac{x}{u(\log x - \log u)}\biggr)\,du \\
\end{align*}
I know that $\pi(u) \sim \operatorname{Li}(u)$, but I am struggling to see why this asymptotic relation holds. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Daniel Fischer is missing the term $\pi(\sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log \sqrt{x}}$ in the last two steps though. Replacing $\pi$ by $\text{Li}$ can be justified by introducing an error term.

Comment: @Gary Oh I see, thank you!